# FSRM File Screening: allow to delete old files

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-server

As a result of a new company policy, I've to apply File Screening for audio and video files on the corporate NAS, specifically on the profiles of the users . I've made some tests, and it works perfectly, except for the users not being able to delete their old files, as the new policy asks them for.

I guess this a "it's a feature, not a bug" thing, and there's no solution to it; but I'm trying to get at least a workaround. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not the users were not able to delete their files, but they were not able to send those files to the Recycle Bin! From the perspective of the FSRM, the users were trying to MOVE files from one location to another, WRITING them in a location which was forbidden, not allowing that.

Actually deleting the files (caps+delete) works flawless.